# Can a function have two slopes?

Tags: calculus

I have done some computation on an ODE and got a strange result.
The ODE is:

$$Ay=y'$$
$$A\begin{vmatrix}
30&64&23\\
-11&-23&-9\\
6&15&4
\end{vmatrix}$$

The resulting solution is given in the image:

[image: Solution]

Then, I do the following:

$$g(x) = \ln(|y_1(x)^2 + y_2(x)^2 + y_3(x)^2|) $$

and I get a function with two different slopes, changing at the origin. Does anyone know why?

[image: Double-Slope]

Comment: You have an unbalanced bracket in your formula for $g$.

Comment: Thanks, fixed....

Comment: Apparently the function $g$ is not differentiable at $x=0$. A simpler example would be $f(x) = |x|$.

Comment: Does that necessarily generate a different slope before and after x=0?

Comment: @Luthier415Hz you have an absolute value in your function. It's not differentiable at zero and you should expect different slopes on each side of the origin. This is perfectly normal.

Comment: Please provide the original ODE. It may be an interesting source of information, instead of the solutions.

Comment: @Crostul I added the ODE.

Comment: The matrix $A$  is wrong. The provided answer says that the eigenvalues of $A$ must be $1, \; 5 + 2 i,  \;  5 - 2 i$

Comment: Corrected.......

Comment: @CyclotomicField based on the solution g(x), does anything in it suggests why we get these two slopes? That is, can we spot this in the ODE? I suspect it has to do with the properties of the logarithm

Comment: next, do you know how to diagonalize the matrix  $A?\; \; $   This is what is expected when you are going to calculate $e^{At}$   You must find an invertible matrix $P$  with $P^{-1} A P = D$  is diagonal.

Comment: This is not part of the task.